# the best way to solve "variable 'xxx' was declared but never referenced"

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, warnings, armcc

**-Pre-condition:**

I know it has many ways to ignore this warning, but I do need fix it but NOT just add some flags for compiler to ignore it, because I can do this makefile `CFLAG` modification on my local, but the compile/build policy can NOT been changed due to company quality control reason. This question I just want to discus who to fix it in a good way but NOT ignore them, many thanks!

Meanwhile, not ONLY some variables are never referenced, but also it has warning:

```
function 'xxx' was declared but never referenced
```

the similar problem in head file, it has some static functions, which ONLY use in one c file but many others c files include this head file.

**Furthermore, this code run on a dedicate target, which has critical memory consumption, that means I need take care of each bit both in ROM and RAM.**

**-------Problem shows in below-----------**

I currently build some codes, which provide by vendor and it contains lots of warning, because I want to have a warning free build, therefore, I put `-Werror` for `gcc` and `--diag_error=[error_ref_number]` for `armcc`.

After above makefile modification, the most warning I currently meet is

```
variable 'xxx' was declared but never referenced
```

It caused by following coding style:

in `veryBIG.h`, it defined some variables like (just for example but the vendor's code has exactly the same way):

```
static const int a = 10;
static const int b = 20;
static const int c = 30;
...
static const int z = xx;
```

however, many c files include this BIG head file, but ONLY one of these c file use one of above variables, it like `a.c` will use variable `a`, `b.c` use variable `b`, etc,.

I have two ways to fix:

1. move these kind of variables into it dedicate c file, and it means head file become useless
2. separate head files, means I create `a.h`, `b.h`, ..., `z.h`, and each dedicate c file include ONLY one of above head file

However, both of these two ways have limitation for my work,

**Way 1**:

I'm NOT sure if vendor further update will change this head file to what or have some update values, because vendor do NOT want to fix this compile warnings, that means if I follow way 1, I will manually update these variables if it has been changed by vendor (ONLY in head file, and I must synchronize them to c file) and this way makes my further merge work become complicated

**Way 2**:

It also makes my further merge work become NOT easy, because I do NOT use the vendor way and I also need modify the system makefile to adapt these head files into `INC` PATH if they are NOT locate in same folder (which the PATH already define for that `veryBIG.h`)

If there any idea to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE**

I can temporary use `Wno-xxx` for `gcc` and delete some `[error_ref_number]` in flag `--diag_error` (like `CFLAG += --diag_error=550,223,188,177,....,`, and I delete `177` for pass this warning in `armcc`) and makes my compile go on and first fix others warnings, but I do need fix ALL warning.

Comment: is it acceptable to suppress such warning in your makefile?  using -Wno-unused-variable

Comment: @tristan, currently no, because this project QA required **ALL** warning free. I use your way to temporary make compile goes on and fix others warning first, I use `-Wno-unused-variable` for `gcc` and I delete some `[error_ref_number]` in flag `--diag_error=` for `armcc`

Comment: @HowChen : I think **all warning free** requirement means removing all those warnings which may create potential bugs in future. I don't think a few extra variables allocated statically can create problem. I welcome your suggestions regarding scenarios where they may create problem.

Comment: Can you edit the header file to conditionally declare those variables, when some `MACRO` is defined, And define/undefine same `MACRO` in your C file before including the header.

Comment: @MadHatter, thanks for you suggestion, you means `variable 'xxx' was declared but never referenced` have no **RISK**??

Comment: @MadHatter: The fact that the programmer at one point thought those variables were necessary but eventually didn't reference them is a potential bug in itself. Perhaps some refactoring that has been done halfway, leaving algorithms in unstable state. Perhaps a typo in a macro. In any case, it's a code smell.

Comment: @HowChen : I have suggested one method in my other comment.

Comment: fwiw: you may suppress this warning in specific compile unit by using the gcc directive   #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

Comment: @DevSolar : As OP described in his problem (or As I understood it), the variables **are used** but not neccessarily all are used by same C source. However, the header is included in all the C files.

Comment: You are trapped in a very bad design choice of your vendor. If these are really only integer constants that they want to make accessible, they should have chosen to use `enum` values. If you are thinking of scripting that file you might just do this: change all `static const int toto = something` to `enum { toto = something }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about memory usage to the point where every bit matters, then you probably *should* break up that header file into many small pieces, because there is no actual guarantee that the compiler *won't* emit every single one of those `static` variables and functions over and over in every single `.c` file even though only a few of them are used.  (The as-if rule says the compiler *may* delete all the unused statics, but nothing says it *has to*.)

In your shoes I would probably write some sort of script which would automatically do the break-up; then I wouldn't have to do it all over again when new releases happened.

Comment: I'm thinking about this way to use some script to break that head file

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the warning **variable 'xxx' was declared but never referenced** has **NO RISK** at all for modern devices. The only threat is that the variable may take up a little memory space when the program is loaded, even the smallest modern machines won't suffer OOM with just that little memory waste. BTW modern compilers will optimize that for you, why won't they since the compiler is already warning you about it. You can just ignore the warning.

If you find the warning annoying, just add the -Wno-unused-variable flag during compilation.

Edit: As Alex says in the comment, I'm wrong. But you can see, that even that little risk I mentioned is fake. So just relax.

Almost all open source projects I know will have unreferenced variables, and I don't see any one making much effort to eliminate that.

**Edit Again:** Alright, I see that you need absolute warning free. Well the only solution I can think of that requires you less hours of work is to use #define macros.

You make blocks of #ifdef/#else/#endif in your header file, and add #defines in your C files. But then you still have to use lots of time figuring out the dependencies.

Your header file would look something like this:

```
#ifdef __A__
static const int var_used_in_A;
#endif
#ifdef __B__
static const int var_used_in_B;
#endif
#ifdef __EXTRA__
static const int var_used_in_both;
#endif
```

and your A.c file would look something like this:

```
#define __A__
#define __EXTRA__
#include "BigHeader.h"
.....
```

That how the glext.h works for OpenGL. This is better than breaking into lots of smaller header files, as you can see the dependencies clearly with the MACROS, while lots of files will require you to make good documentation. And Macros are more flexible than files.

It would be nice if you can negotiate with the VENDOR you mentioned for them to always tell you the difference they made, and you can just add those to the correct place. If you can't just keep histories of the original VeryBIG.h and use a diff tool to examine the changes of the new one.

Comment: Static const variable does not " take up a little memory space". It exists only at compile time.

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer the OP question.

Comment: I don't want to ignore them, I need have a good way to fix it

Comment: I think it is the easiest way right now, many thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Can you write?

```c
static_assert(x == x);
```

or

```c
assert(x == x);
```

These are removed at compile time.